# Two ubuntu 16.04 server run unattended upgrade, one need restart.

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, unattended

I have two `Ubuntu server 16.04.`

I have enabled `unattended upgrade` for the `two servers` and the `same configuration.`

He `upgrades one package` the same version into the two servers but `only one` he shows me the message that needs a `reboot`.

Anyone know why only one of the server need reboot?

> Unattended upgrade returned: True
>
> Warning: A reboot is required to complete this upgrade.
>
> Packages that were upgraded: A

Answer (score 0):

Which package is it? Try to install `needrestart` and see if that suggests that you need to reboot the servers.

Comment: The package it was the tcpdump, but it was not the first time this happens on the two servers.
Thank you for your answer.